# How to properly list files of a directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, getdirectories

I was using below code until I get too many images. So I wanted to make a method in the master page cs file class to rather generate the HTML for me.

```
<img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/1.png") %>">
```

But as long I get a lot of images I wrote this method to generate the HTML:

```
public void GenerateSlideItems()
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images"));
            foreach(string file in files)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                Response.Write(string.Format(
                                            "<img src=\"{0}\"  class=\"img-responsive\" alt=\"{1}\">",
                                            file, filename));
            }
        }
```

But I'm getting the images like `C:\...\visual studio\project\etc\1.png` rather `http:\\localhost:5090\images\1.png` how do I do that? I also tried with and without `ResolveUrl()` but it ended up returning something like `C:\images\1.png` which obviously isn't the correct path I'm looking for. I new to ASP.NET I don't know yet how those things are usually done. I'm learning.

Comment: i don't see you use resolve URL in your other example.

Comment: This was what I tried before `Server.MapPath()`. I didn't put that code in the question actually. Just mentioned I did it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to look back at what you were originally doing and replicate the functionality:

```
ResolveUrl("~/images/1.png")
```

You have a server-side file system path, and you need to turn it into a URL.  Since `file` contains the file name, and you have a hard-coded path from where you got the files, you should be able to combine those values:

```
var root = "~/images"
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(root));
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
    var filenameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

    var serverUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", root, filename);
    var browserUrl = ResolveUrl(serverUrl);
    // now you should be able to use browserUrl in your manually-built HTML...

    Response.Write(string.Format(
                                "<img src=\"{0}\" class=\"img-responsive\" alt=\"{1}\">",
                                browserUrl, filenameWithoutExtension));
}
```

The reason for the extra step in turning the "server URL" to a "browser URL" is because the `~` path won't mean anything to a browser.  And since you're manually writing this HTML to the response, the framework never has a chance to translate that path for you.

Comment: Does make difference if I'm using this within Visual Studio? i.e, rather copying files to IIS's www folder I'm building it from visual studio by pressing F5 on my ASP.NET webForm project. I'm getting the root path combined with `c:\..\physical\path\to\1.png` like this: `\images\c:\..\physical\path\to\1.png`

Comment: Directory.GetFiles returns the fullpath not just the filename, need to call Path.GetFileName from that loop

Comment: @Jack: That doesn't make a difference.  But Steve's comment afterward does.  I've updated the code accordingly.  Basically, in order to be used on a website the path must be a "URL" path, not a file system path.

Comment: I understand that I have to convert it from a file system path to Url but I didn't manage to do that. I tried your code but what it does is concat the path with the full path filename and return. I tried just `ResolveUrl(file)` and it return the physical file path and not an Url

Comment: @Jack: Did you try the updated version of the answer?  You'll need to use `Path.GetFileName()` before concatenating the values.

Comment: @David: Sorry my lack of attention. I hadn't see `Path.GetFileName()` call. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images");
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have the base path for your website: `Server.MapPath("~");`

So replace `Server.MapPath("~")` with your domain name on all your image paths.